# Term for which the net effect of a number of actions is zero?

Tags: single-word-requests

If there are one or more actions take and the net effect is no effect, what is a word for this?

Comment: Do you mean something like "damned if you do, damned if you don’t"? That nothing changes regardless of any action. Can you give a simple example?

Comment: A word or phrase request can easily attract a long list of answers when it’s too subjective – more of a poll or request for ideas. Unfortunately neither are a good fit for the Stack Exchange model. A Stack Exchange question is objective and specific enough that it has a clearly “right” answer. See: “[Real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”, “[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160)”.

Comment: Add details of research you’ve done, especially solutions you’ve already rejected, and why. Include the desired connotation, register (formality), part of speech, and context in which it is to be used, and provide the exact enclosing sentence or passage. If this is not possible because you really do have a subjective question, a welcoming place to ask for advice is our [English Language & Usage Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95).

Answer (score 2):

When actions negate one another's effect, it's also called a *wash*.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that each individually has an effect, but together they don't, that would be "cancelling". If it the same thing, and it's done twice, that could be called "toggle". A math term for something that when repeated has no effect is "idempotent".

Answer (score 1):

There is an expression that could provide an answer.  The 'zero sum game' sounds as if it might fit the bill, but in its origin, from game theory, it relates to something slightly different.  The idea was to explore games, such as chess, in which either one player wins and the other loses, in which case the sum is zero - i.e. (+1) + (-1) = 0.   It is possible to extend this idea to embrace your idea that the net sum of actions taken by one individual have the same number of positive and negative outcomes.

There is an alternative expression:  'zero-sum outcome'.  That might do, but I have not so far been able to track down examples.

You could in theory take a chance and use the expression.  I am sure it would be understood. You can signal that you are stretching the meaning of the expression by putting it in single quotes (sometimes called 'scare quotes', to show it is being used in an unusual context.

Answer (score 0):

You almost have the word **ineffectual** which in the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ineffectual) means

> Not producing any significant or desired effect.